# I want to use the icon of vaccine but it does not work when I add its code

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, google-material-icons

this is my code for that :-

```
Icon(
    Icons.vaccines_outlined,
),
```

I get this error when I added the code:-
The getter 'vaccines_outlined' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'.
Try importing the library that defines 'vaccines_outlined', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'vaccines_outlined'.

Comment: seems flutter `iconData` doesnt contain `vaccines_outlined,`

Answer (score 0):

where did you find this icon! it seems that flutter icons do not have this one! Search through the icons in this [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the Material Icon "vaccines" as [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=vaccines).

You should download it and add it to your assets as it is not present in the flutter library yet.

If you don't know how to add an assets please refer to [this documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

You need to add it to your pubspec.yaml and copy it in your assets folder.